# No matching function call that only appears when creating object in different file

Tags: c++

I'm currently running into a no matching function call error in C++ that reads like this

```
TestSuiteAssignment4.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
TestSuiteAssignment4.cpp:533: error: no matching function for call to 
‘CreatureStack::CreatureStack(Creature*&)’
CreatureStack.hpp:32: note: candidates are: 
CreatureStack::CreatureStack(Creature*, CreatureStack*)
CreatureStack.hpp:31: note: CreatureStack::CreatureStack()
CreatureStack.hpp:18: note: CreatureStack::CreatureStack(const CreatureStack&)
```

.

The weird thing is that I don't get any of these errors when I'm creating an object through the main function in the implementation files of CreatureStack. It is only when I try to create an object in the TestSuiteAssignment4.cpp file that I get this error.

Here is the CreatureStack.hpp file.

```
class CreatureStack
{
     private: 
         CreatureStack* next;
    CreatureStack* last;
    CreatureStack* first;
    Creature* item;

public:
    int count;
    Creature* remove();
    void add(Creature* item);
    bool empty();
    int returnCount();
    CreatureStack();
    CreatureStack(Creature* creature, CreatureStack* nextArg);

};
```

Here is the constructors for CreatureStack in the implementation file CreatureStack.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CreatureStack.hpp"
#include "Creature.hpp"
#include "Goblin.hpp"


 /****************************************************************************
 ** Function: default constructor
 ** Description: constructs instacklist object
 ** Parameters: none
 ** Pre-conditions: no object created
 ** Post-conditions: object created
 ****************************************************************************/


CreatureStack::CreatureStack()
{
}



 /****************************************************************************
 ** Function: constructor
 ** Description: constructs object with arguments
 ** Parameters: int item, and pointer to next intstacklist object
 ** Pre-conditions: no object created
 ** Post-conditions: object created
 ****************************************************************************/



 CreatureStack::CreatureStack(Creature* creature, CreatureStack* nextArg = NULL)
 {
/*initiate object with the item argument, and a pointer to an IntStackList Object for Next */

item = creature;
next = nextArg;
count = 1;
last = this;
}
```

Here is the main file for the CreatureStack Implementation File

```
int main()
{


Creature* test1 = new Goblin();
Creature* test2 = new Goblin();
Creature* test3 = new Goblin();

Creature* testPoint;

test1->setId(1);
test2->setId(2);
test3->setId(3);

CreatureStack stack1 = CreatureStack(test1);
stack1.add(test2);
stack1.add(test3);
}
```

When I run these lines of code, there are no constructor problems/compile problems at all.

It is only when I create a new file, TestSuiteAssignment4.cpp, that I run into the compiling errors with the constructor.

In the new file, I have only the following code.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Dice.hpp"
#include "CreatureStack.hpp"
#include "CreatureQueue.hpp"
#include "Creature.hpp"
#include "Goblin.hpp"

int main()
{

    Creature* test1 = new Goblin();
    Creature* test2 = new Goblin();
    Creature* test3 = new Goblin();

    Creature* testPoint;

    test1->setId(1);
    test2->setId(2);
    test3->setId(3);

    CreatureStack stack1 = CreatureStack(test1);
    stack1.add(test2);
    stack1.add(test3);

}
```

The no matching function error call that I get when I try to compile TestSuiteAssignment4.cpp is confusing to me, because I get no problems at all when I'm trying to create an CreatureStack object within the CreatureStack implementation file. However, when I put the same exact code into TestSuiteAssignment4.cpp I get a matching function call error that never came up at all while testing in the implementation file.

Thanks for any possible help.

Comment: You should paste the exact error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the default value (below) to header file

```
CreatureStack::CreatureStack(Creature* creature, CreatureStack* nextArg = NULL)
```

Comment: that worked! thanks! the problem was that originally I had it that line of code in my header file . However, when I tried to compile, it gave me a compile error for defining a default value twice; To fix it earlier, I decided to change the header file rather than the implementation file, which was probably why it didn't cause any problems for the implementation; I should have changed the implementation file rather than the header file; your suggestion fixed it. thanks for your help!